Youtube API broken response
I'm trying to use websocket in Python to get all comments from a video but for some reason some times the response comes broken or my code breaks it as shown here at "updatedAt": "20
90
24-05-23T04:32:43Z". this should come in one single line but its breaking line and my code :
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "tDBWc_n2heSBY8O1O5pmnreVtLs",
      "id": "Ugx44hu-DqxbmnInPQp4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
        "videoId": "1KEtxTQUzxY",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "uTgV5p5VmHXEqonQjGj4nXMh2m8",
          "id": "Ugx44hu-DqxbmnInPQp4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "channelId": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
            "videoId": "1KEtxTQUzxY",
            "textDisplay": "I wonder if this would be a good product for people who want to practice   rollerskating but don&#39;t have lots of space ",
            "textOriginal": "I wonder if this would be a good product for people who want to practice rollerskating but don't have lots of space ",
            "authorDisplayName": "@denden8372",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AIdro_k1FwzFYDNQwpt1EpUQ_ghYZQrg5uxdzopNsKu3i9MGFkU=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/@denden8372",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCRuGL6tDdqJZXekXlali8hQ"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2024-05-23T04:31:57Z",
            "updatedAt": "20
90
24-05-23T04:32:43Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    }
  ]
}

I'm connecting to the port 443 of youtube api, receiving the response in bytes, decoding in utf-8  and trying to parse it to json but, with the example above, json.load can't do it. Here's my code:
import socket
import ssl
import json
import re

# Your YouTube API key
API_KEY = 'AIzaSyBYEN3s2iRoDREu4qK3ieS1fTACdbsjXkc'
VIDEO_ID = '1KEtxTQUzxY'
HOST = 'www.googleapis.com'
PORT = 443


def create_request(video_id, page_token=None):
    base_url = f'/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId={video_id}&key={API_KEY}&maxResults=20'
    if page_token:
        base_url += f'&pageToken={page_token}'
    request = f"GET {base_url} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {HOST}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
    return request


def fetch_comments(video_id):
    comments = []
    page_token = None

    while True:
        request = create_request(video_id, page_token)

        # Create a socket and wrap it with SSL for HTTPS
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=HOST) as ssock:
            ssock.connect((HOST, PORT))
            ssock.sendall(request.encode('utf-8'))

            response = b''
            while True:
                data = ssock.recv(4096)
                if not data:
                    break
                response += data

        response = response.decode('utf-8')
        headers, body =re.split('\r\n\r\n....\r\n',response)
        body = body.rstrip('0\r\n')
        json_body = json.loads(body)

        for item in json_body.get('items', []):
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']
            comments.append(comment)

        page_token = json_body.get('nextPageToken')
        if not page_token:
            break

    return comments


if __name__ == "__main__":
    all_comments = fetch_comments(VIDEO_ID)
    for comment in all_comments:
        print(comment)

I've tried rewriting the code 20 times but I can't solve this.

Why not just using requests.get(f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId={video_id}&key={API_KEY}&maxResults=20').json()?

My teacher wants me to use socket
